# JINJA2+ANSIBLE SYNTAX ERROR

Tags: jinja2

I have a long JINJA2 file used to deploy Elastic application over a set of servers.

The Ansible task to deploy the application is working fine, but task to deploy the application config file is failing and returning the error message below:

> fatal: [HOSTNAME.ACME.COM] =>
>   {'msg': "TypeError: argument of type 'StrictUndefined' is not iterable", 'failed': True}

I really believe that there is an error in the JINJA2 file, but was not able to find it out so far.

Could someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: No way to narrow down where any error in the JIJNA2 file might be?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any line nor peace of code to link the error. I have checked all {,[ and ( to be sure all of them are opened/closed and they are. This was the only point that I had in mind to check.